# ArrayDeque contains Object?

Tags: java, arraydeque

I'm creating a  rudimentary inventory system with an ArrayDeque where things are pushed into an inventory.

```
Couch couch1 = new Couch("I wouldn't sit on it.", 100, true);
roomList[0].inventory.add(couch1);
```

I'm running a check to see if an item is in a room like this.

```
if (input.matches(".*look.*"))
{
    if(input.matches(".*Couch.*"))
    {
        if(roomList[currentRoom].inventory.contains(???))
        {
            //code to be executed.
        }
    }
}
```

What do I put into the ??? in order for it to check if the inventory ArrayDeque contains the object couch1? If this isn't possible, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you put `couch1` there?

Comment: you want to check is there a certain object in the collection but you have no idea what that object is in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The `contains()` function is based on your implementation of `equals()`. By default you have to provide exactly the same object (so `couch1`). If you override you can make your own version of equals, for instance by comparing all the fields. A very helpful tool for this is Apache [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html), this also explains how to implement the `equals()` function.

The downside then is that you have to construct a couch object with the same fields. If that is not possible you might be able to resort to another data type, such as a map. You can then store by a unique id based on some of the fields of the couch.

A final alternative is to not use the `contains()` function and instead make your own function that loops over the `Deque` and filters based on some other selection criteria.